# How to change link in a view depending on state of a certain field

Tags: views

I have a content type called conference, there are two types of conferences; supported and unsupported.

Supported have their own node inside Drupal, unsupported link out to external websites rather than having their own node. Supported also have the same external link.

There is a field selection for this in the conference content type so the user picks whether a conference is supported or unsupported.

Now I have a view of conferences and their title is a link. However I need to check whether each conference is supported or unsupported, as this link will either be a link to the node or a link externally.

Looking for any suggestions on how to achieve this, I'm guessing views PHP would achieve this, but is this the best option?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the field token of the field which is used to picks whether a conference is supported or unsupported. Then you can link it to a node or external link,

Comment: But I need logic to check the state of this field, and to change the title's link depending on this. So in the case of it being unsupported the token for the href will be [field_unsupported_link] and in the case if it being supported it will simply link to that nodes content page

Comment: You need to use the field token of the of the field which is used to pick whether each conference is supported or unsupported. This will give you the whether a conference is supported or not. Then you can put condition to link it internally to a node or externally

Comment: Ok yes, but how to create this condition in a view?